# Asp.net MVC 2 ValidationInput

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I using ValidationInput(false) at my Action, but ASP.NET MVC 2 P2 still validating my request. Why? Is it a bug of Preview 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Visual Studio 2010?  If so, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019843/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-in-mvc-2-asp-net-4-0).

Comment: Worked. But, by default, ASP.NET no more control this behavior?

Comment: By default in .NET 4, it occurs very early in the pipeline (before any module or handler runs).  This means that it can't be disabled by MVC since MVC runs so late.  If you revert back to the v2 behavior, MVC can suppress it.

One of the advantages of the .NET 4 behavior is that you can customize the particular checks performed by input validation.  The whitepaper linked in that answer gives you more information on how to do that.